# Still not working- function: letter to next letter(i.e. a->b) and capitalize vowels

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, unicode, alphabet

I keep getting "Type Error: str.join is not a function. This code is supposed to take a string input and make each letter in the input the next letter(i.e. a->b,z->a) and capitalize every vowel. Does anyone know why it's still wrong?

```
str = str.split("");//split() string into array
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;str++){//for loop that checks each letter
    if(str[i].match(/[a-y]/i)){
      str[i]=String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0)+1);
        }else if(str[i].match('z')){
          str[i] = 'a';
        }
    if(str[i].match(/[aeiou]/i)){
       str[i] = str[i].toUpperCase();
       }

  }
   str2= str.join('');
  //modifies letter by adding up in alphabet
  //capitalizes each vowel
  //join() string


  return str2; 
}

// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accidentally incrementing `str` when you should be incrementing `i`:

```
for(var i=0;i<str.length;str++){//for loop that checks each letter
                          ^---// replace str with i
```

I don't know if the rest of your code works, but this would explain that particular error.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of the loop you have `for(var i=0;i<str.length;str++){`, change that to `for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){` (you're looping based on an iteration that doesn't exist)